# jQuery Mobile Remove Styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When using jQuery Mobile, if there is any new form element that is append to the form with jQuery will not have the styling by default. But the styling can be applied via this:

```
$('#gender').selectmenu();
```

Seems we can apply styling to element, so is it possible to remove the styling that has been applied to form element? If possible, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just do `$('#gender').attr("class","")`?

Comment: @user1094553 Tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: @user1094553: no, you can't just remove CSS classes; jQuery Mobile enhancements may involve also child elements and creating new elements (`<div>`s for example)

Comment: @user1995781: in which case do you need to apply then remove the styling? is it feasible to keep two copies of the same element (with and without style)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the **[destroy](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-destroy)** method on the widget to remove jQM styling:

```
$("#gender").selectmenu( "destroy" );
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rMG4Z/1/)**